# stein's complex analysis, functions of finite order.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality

An entire function $f$ is said to be of finite order if there exists $\rho > 0$ and constants $A, B>0$ such that 
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:growth order}
  \lvert f(z)\rvert \leq Ae^{B\lvert z\rvert^\rho} \qquad \forall z\in\mathbb{C}
 \end{equation}
    The growth order of $f$ is $\rho_f = \inf \rho$ where the infimum is taken over all $\rho > 0$ for which there exists constants $A, B$ such that the above equation holds.

Let $n(r)$ denote the number of zeroes of a function $f$ in the disk of radius $r$ about the origin.

Stein's theorem 2.1 states that if $f$ is entire and $\rho_f \leq \rho$, then there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $n(r) \leq Cr^\rho$ for all sufficiently large $r$. Here, $n(r)$ denotes the number of zeroes in a disk about the origin of radius $r$.

PROOF.Suppose first that $f(0) \neq 0$ and note that since $n(r)$ is an increasing function, 
    $$
  n(r) = \frac{n(r)}{\log(2)}\int_r^{2r}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}{x} \leq \frac{1}{\log(2)}\int_r^{2r}\frac{n(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}{x}
 $$
    By the previous lemma,
    $$
  \int_r^{2r}\frac{n(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}{x} \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log\lvert f\left(2re^{it}\right)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}{t} - \lvert f(0)\rvert 
 $$
Then for all sufficiently large $r$;
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\log\lvert f(2re^{it})\rvert dt\leq \int_0^{2\pi}\log\lvert A\exp\{B(2r)^\rho\} \rvert \,\mathrm{d}t \leq C r^\rho
$$
for some constant $C$.

Why do we need $r$ to be large? I am wondering if the assumption can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the assumption that $f(0) \neq 0$, the restriction "for sufficiently large $r$" is necessary, since $C\cdot r^{\rho} \to 0$ as $r \to 0$ for every $\rho > 0$, and the unrestricted inequality can thus only hold if $n(r) = 0$ for sufficiently small $r$, i.e. $f(0) \neq 0$.

With the assumption $f(0) \neq 0$, since there is a $\delta > 0$ with $f(z) \neq 0$ for $\lvert z\rvert < \delta$, the constant $C$ can be chosen large enough that the inequality $n(r) \leqslant C\cdot r^{\rho}$ holds for all $r$.

However, one needs the strict inequality $\rho > \rho_f$ to guarantee such a bound, it can fail for $\rho = \rho_f$. For example $f(s) = (s-1)\zeta(s)$, where $\zeta$ is the Riemann $\zeta$-function, is an entire function of order $1$, and

$$n(r) \sim \frac{r\log r}{2\pi}$$

for this $f$.